Qt: How to read the state of a checkbox in a QTableWidget?
I’m trying to read the state of a checkbox in a QTableWidget. I would like to read out the status regardless of the name of the chekbox, i know where it is in the table
using this code:
//insert a checkbox into the tableWidget_1
QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget();
QCheckBox* test_checkbox = new QCheckBox();


test_checkbox->setText("delet");
QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
pLayout->addWidget(test_checkbox);
pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
ui->tableWidget_1->setCellWidget(0, 3, pWidget);


//try to read it out
QWidget *widget = ui->tableWidget_1->cellWidget(3, 0);
QCheckBox *checkbox = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(widget);
int state= widget->checkState();
qDebug() << state;

If i replace the dynamic_cast with qobject_cast it doesn't work either.
Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this? Thanks a lot, this is my first question :)
marv

You have a discrepancy in your indices:
ui->tableWidget_1->setCellWidget(0, 3, pWidget); // <<-- column 3


//try to read it out
QWidget *widget = ui->tableWidget_1->cellWidget(3, 0); // <<-- row 3

Also, always use qobject_cast for casting QObjects.

Thanks for pointing it out, I have changed it.
When I get to the line "int state = checkbox->checkState();"
the programme crashes with the message:
Name of the signal :
SIGSEGV
Meaning :
Segmentation fault

setCellWidget() is used against pWidget, which is the container widget that contains the QCheckBox. What you're actually doing is like trying to access checkState() of pWidget, which obviously doesn't have such a member. Get the cellWidget(), check for its check box using findChild(QCheckBox) and eventually, if found, use checkState() with its result, if it's not null. Alternatively, create a QWidget subclass and expose check state getter/setter members that eventually access the inner checkbox.
